# Python Pandas Dataframe - Fill Empty Columns with calculation that uses row value and column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df, which can be created with this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
#create the dates to make into columns
datestart=datetime.date(2018,1,1)
dateend=datetime.date(2018,1,5)
newcols=pd.date_range(datestart,dateend).date
#create the test data
d={'name':['a','b','c','d'],'earlydate': [datetime.date(2018,1,1),datetime.date(2018,1,3),datetime.date(2018,1,4),datetime.date(2018,1,5)]}
#create initial test dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
#create the new dataframe with empty newcols
df=pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(columns=newcols)])
```

AND Looks like this:

```
df
Out[17]: 
  name   earlydate 2018-01-01    ...     2018-01-03 2018-01-04 2018-01-05
0    a  2018-01-01        NaN    ...            NaN        NaN        NaN
1    b  2018-01-03        NaN    ...            NaN        NaN        NaN
2    c  2018-01-04        NaN    ...            NaN        NaN        NaN
3    d  2018-01-05        NaN    ...            NaN        NaN        NaN

[4 rows x 7 columns]
```

What I am looking to do is fill all of the empty newcols with the difference in days between the newcol name and the earlydate (newcolname(which is a date)-earlydate(which is a date).  I want to do this dataframe 'wise', and not use a function,lambda,apply, or a for loop.  I am fairly certain this should be able to be done dataframe wise, not column or row wise.

The result/expected ending df can be created with this:

```
dresultdata={'name':['a','b','c','d'],
         'earlydate': [datetime.date(2018,1,1),datetime.date(2018,1,3),datetime.date(2018,1,4),datetime.date(2018,1,5)],
         datetime.date(2018,1,1):[0,-2,-3,-4], #this is the difference in days between the column name and the earlydate
         datetime.date(2018,1,2):[-1,1,2,3],
         datetime.date(2018,1,3):[-2,0,1,2],
         datetime.date(2018,1,4):[-3,-1,0,1]}
dferesult=pd.DataFrame(data=dresultdata)
```

And looks like this:

```
dferesult
Out[19]: 
  name   earlydate  2018-01-01  2018-01-02  2018-01-03  2018-01-04
0    a  2018-01-01           0          -1          -2          -3
1    b  2018-01-03          -2           1           0          -1
2    c  2018-01-04          -3           2           1           0
3    d  2018-01-05          -4           3           2           1
```

I have made this work by looping as follows:

```
for d in newcols:
    df.loc[:,d]=d-df.earlydate
```

But it takes forever for large frames (1m rows).  Ideas welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC:

```
i = pd.to_datetime(df.earlydate.values).values
j = pd.to_datetime(df.columns[2:]).values

df.iloc[:, 2:] = (j - i[:, None]).astype('timedelta64[D]').astype(int)

df

    earlydate name 2018-01-01 2018-01-02 2018-01-03 2018-01-04 2018-01-05
0  2018-01-01    a          0          1          2          3          4
1  2018-01-03    b         -2         -1          0          1          2
2  2018-01-04    c         -3         -2         -1          0          1
3  2018-01-05    d         -4         -3         -2         -1          0
```

Comment: Numpy has a name `numpy.newaxis` that is used to extend an array into another dimension.  That `np.newaxis` is just `None` so I can use `None` instead.  What it does is it turns `i` from an array with shape `(4,)` to shape `(4,1)` and that enables me to do subtract and invoke Numpy's broadcasting.